# Identify the vector given its coordinates and the ordered basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically as it says in the title. Given the ordered basis $T = \{t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n\}$ and a vector $v$, I understand how to get the coordinate vector $[v]_T$. However, I can't figure out how to get $v$ when given the ordered basis $T$ and coordinate vector $[v]_T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T = \{t_1, \dots, t_n\}$ be an ordered basis for a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. For any $v \in V$, there are unique $c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $v = c_1t_1 + \dots + c_nt_n$. We call the column vector consisting of $c_1, \dots, c_n$ the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $T$ and we denote it by $[v]_T$. More precisely,

$$[v]_T = \left[\begin{matrix}c_1\\ \vdots\\ c_n\end{matrix}\right] \in \mathbb{F}^n.$$

So, given $T$ and $[v]_T$, we can determine $v \in V$ by computing $v = c_1t_1 + \dots + c_nt_n$.